# Google map marker not showing in Android with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

i'm having problems with map markers on Android using Jetpack Compose.
I have followed the official docs but i couldn't find a way to make it work, and i have no idea given that i made exactly the same things the tutorial suggested.

Currently the marker is not showing and the camera position neither. I don't think it is an API key problem given that i receive no warnings or errors about it.
Here's the code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.citylife.ui.theme.CityLifeTheme
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.maps.android.compose.*

class MapActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CityLifeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    MapElement(applicationContext)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MapElement(context: Context) {
    val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
    val singaporeState = MarkerState(position = singapore)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = singaporeState,
            title = "Singapore",
            snippet = "Marker for singapore"
        )
    }

    var uiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(MapUiSettings()) }
    val properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MapProperties(mapType = MapType.NORMAL))
    }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
            properties = properties,
            uiSettings = uiSettings
        )
        Switch(
            checked = uiSettings.zoomControlsEnabled,
            onCheckedChange = {
                uiSettings = uiSettings.copy(zoomControlsEnabled = it)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see i copied from the docs, and everything works fine, but marker and camera positions are not working somehow, do you have any suggest?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please considering marking my answer as correct or providing additional information if it does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have two `GoogleMap` composables and one of them is drawing on top of the other one.

This code will combine the two to give you the marker and the switch composables:

```
@Composable
fun MapElement(context: Context) {
    val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
    val singaporeState = MarkerState(position = singapore)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
    }
    var uiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(MapUiSettings()) }
    val properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MapProperties(mapType = MapType.NORMAL))
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = singaporeState,
            title = "Singapore",
            snippet = "Marker for singapore"
        )
        Switch(
            checked = uiSettings.zoomControlsEnabled,
            onCheckedChange = {
                uiSettings = uiSettings.copy(zoomControlsEnabled = it)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I didn't run this code but it should function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you are using two GoogleMap methods, which overlaps each other. I have written an article on this topic, and also how to make a custom marker on compose:

https://towardsdev.com/jetpack-compose-custom-google-map-marker-erselan-khan-e6e04178a30b